# How do I pass the data that I have submitted in front end to backend using Python in a list?

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAvz7.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4v1k.png)

this is the javascript code that I wrote

```js
function add_row()
{
 var new_sprint=document.getElementById("new_sprint").value;
 var new_month=document.getElementById("new_month").value;
 var new_name=document.getElementById("new_name").value;
 var new_phase=document.getElementById("new_phase").value;
 var new_taskname=document.getElementById("new_taskname").value;
 var new_taskactualtotal=document.getElementById("new_taskactualtotal").value;
 console.log(new_sprint,new_month,new_name,new_phase,new_taskname,new_taskactualtotal)
    
 var table=document.getElementById("data_table");
 var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
 var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td id='sprint_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_sprint+"</td><td id='month_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_month+"</td><td id='name_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_name+"</td><td id='phase_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_phase+"</td><td id='taskname_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_taskname+"</td><td id='taskactualtotal_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_taskactualtotal+"</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button"+table_len+"' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' id='save_button"+table_len+"' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'></td></tr>";

 document.getElementById("new_sprint").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_month").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_name").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_phase").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_taskname").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_taskactualtotal").value="";
}
```

1. List item[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmaTh.png)

this is the UI page where I submit the values

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the input elements' `name` attribute to achieve this.

Like for example:

```
<input type="text" name="values[0]"/>
<input type="text" name="values[1]"/>
<input type="text" name="values[2]"/>
```

When the form is submitted, the backend then receives them as a list of values, where the parameter is called `values` and holds the three inputs' values in it.

Edit: I know this works with a PHP backend, not sure about Python.

Comment: in python there's a request module where we could get the data from front end. it'd helpful for me if i could do it in python. My production code runs in python. so i should do it in python. but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Give a dynamic name in your Javascript to each input. Ensure it is wrapped in a form tag and the data is being sent back in a format your Python API will understand.

As long as the inputs share a similar name you can use Regex in Python to put them in the same object. Or, before the form is submitted have a JavaScript listener on the button that prevents the initial submission packs up all the inputs into their own object then submits the form so your backend only has to read it.

Comment: i understand that. what module and method should i use to get the input from front end? request.post or something like that. i dont know which module or method reads input from post method?

Comment: It depends on what you are using on the backend with Python, if you are using Django or Flask then you have libraries that can intercept the post request's body and help you transcribe it into an object.

Comment: If you are using vanilla Python then you need to develop your own library to take the post request and translate the XML or JSON into a readable object.